# ClickOnce - Restart application with arguments

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I have a `WPF` application, and using ClickOnce for deploying that.
In this app, have a button that used for restart the app with arguments..

The code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location, arg);
if (Application.Current != null)
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

But i see that sometimes the properties are not initialized correct, so after search for a solution - i read this: http://blachniet.com/2012/10/20/how-not-to-restart-a-clickonce-application/

After read - i change as folloing:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();
    if (Application.Current != null)
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

But now - i have problem - Application's restart method - doesn't accept to pass arguments..
How to can i to restart correct with arguments?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of passing arguments, can you just create a config file for your app to read in and use?

Comment: to pass arguments the program should be on, if you want to start with argument you should have some kind of a config file that the program can read from when it starts... on restart you can change those configs and tell the program to restart.

Comment: Yes, i think about it, and i will use this (Save args to a config file), thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I relaunch ClickOnce apps with arguments:

```
var launchUri = "http://yourwebsite.com/yourapp/YourApp.application"
Process.Start(“rundll32.exe”, String.Format(“dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbApplication {0}?Arg1={1}&Arg2={2}&Arg3={3}”, launchUri, arg1Value, arg2Value, arg3Value));
```

Where Arg1, Arg2 and Arg3 are your arguments.

When launching the app, you'll have to parse the args out of the URI yourself.  The URI is available here:

```
var launchUri = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, but AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData always is null, and this solution isn't good, because not all properties are initialized..

Comment: I believe one of the properties in that path will be null if you start in the debugger (because there is no launch uri).  Try logging it out when starting normally to see if you can access it